# how to check if the app was launched by NFC Tag shortcut or manually launched the app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, nfc

I want to launch my flutter app using a NFC Tag and iOS shortcut, or android equivalent and I want to trigger a process if the app was launched by this process. is there a event listen to check if the app was launched or bought back up from the background from the  shortcut automation ?  if there is any source materials for this please link. thank you !

Comment: On iOS you can expect a call to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application to handle the URL if the app is launched from a QR code or nfc tag

Comment: Can you get the event trigger when you listen to NFC tags? If true, then use flutter local notifications (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) then from that notification open the application.